# RAID 1 HDD replacement with used HDD

Tags: hp, raid1

We have an HD Proliant G8 with 2 HDDs built RAID 1.  One of the HDD drive light becomes amber and iLO shows Bay 2 disk has a failure.  I'd like to replace the failed drive with one pulled from other old servers that are idled.  Those used HDD have the same size and model and also built RAID 1 as well.  I've never done this before.  Do I need to "wipe" the old HDD before hot-plugging it into this server?  If so, how do I "wipe" the old disk using this G8 server?  Plug that into say Bay 3, and have HP Intelligent Provisioning help on this (any detailed guide?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P420i? No, you don't have to wipe the drive. Just hot-swap the failed/warning drive and rebuild should be starting.

If there are spare slots, you can also plug the replacement disk into one of those and start a manual replace in ACU - not much of a difference with RAID1 or a totally failed disk, but might speed up rebuilding with RAID5+ and a still generally functional drive.

While you're at it you might want to add a hot spare if you recycle an old drive.

Comment: thanks, yes 420i.  so I don’t even need to do a manual RAID build in HP intelligent provisioning?  Everything is automatic once another HDD is plugged into the failed slot?

Comment: Yes, it should be automatic. You should check whether it works though.

Comment: It worked, automatic.  thanks